# I want to open popup only three times using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created one popup. I want to open it three times. Not all the time

```
<script>

$(window).load(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://ipapi.co/json', function (result) {
        if (result.country == 'IN') {
//            var walk_in = localStorage.getItem('walk_in');
//            if (walk_in == null) {
//                localStorage.setItem('walk_in', 1);
                // Show popup here
                setTimeout(function(){
                $('#walkin').modal('show');
            },2000);
           // }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: add a counter and increament it if the counter is equal to 3 dont open the pop up

Comment: Save the counter in local or sessionStorage

Comment: Set a variable that will increment `one` after each popup. And do checking if this variable is less then or less then equal 3 depend on your initial value for that variable before doing popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// make falsy (null, undefined, empty string) = 0
var walk_in = localStorage.getItem('walk_in') || 0; 
walk_in++; // cast to number and increment
if (walk_in<=3) {
  $.getJson( .... 
    if (result.country == 'IN') {
      localStorage.setItem('walk_in', walk_in);
```

testing `stringVar++` :

```js
var counter = ""
console.log(counter,typeof counter)
counter = counter || 0
console.log(counter,typeof counter)

counter = "1"
console.log(counter,typeof counter)
counter = counter || 0
counter++; // casts and adds
console.log(counter,typeof counter)
```

Comment: Need to add var walk_in = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('walk_in')) || 0;